# Select users with most deleted classifieds along with number of classifieds

Tags: mysql, sql

From a table like below, how can I select the users with the most deleted classifieds along with the number of deleted classifieds? Over here: 6 = deleted. I'm using mySql.

```
"userid"    "classStatus"
"1"         "6"
"1"         "6"
"2"         "0"
"2"         "6"
"3"         "0"
"3"         "0"
```

So in this case, the output'll be:

```
"userid"    "numberofClassifieds"
"1"         "2"
"2"         "1"
```

I'm ok with basic sql statements, but can't see to find a way to do this.

```
select max(count(classStatus)) as t, userid as u from testtops where classStatus=6;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you lack `GROUP BY` in your query,

```
SELECT userid, COUNT(*) NumberOfClassified
FROM tableName
WHERE classStatus = 6
GROUP BY userID
ORDER BY NumberOfClassified DESC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/039df/1)

Comment: Merry Christmas to you too :-)

Answer (score 1):

This will select all users that have at least one deleted classfield, and it will show the number of all classfields and the number of all deleted classfields:

```
SELECT
  userid,
  count(*) as numberofClassifieds,
  sum(classStatus=6) as numberofDeletedClassfields
FROM
  your_table
GROUP BY userid
HAVING numberofDeletedClassfields>0
ORDER BY numberofDeletedClassfields DESC
```

**EDIT:** this is an alternative that uses joins, it doesn't look as much elegant as the other query, but it's certanly faster:

```
SELECT dc.userid, c.numberofClassfields, dc.numberofDeletedClassfields
FROM
  (select userid, count(*) as numberofDeletedClassfields
   from your_table
   where classStatus = 6
   group by userid
   having count(*)>0) dc
  INNER JOIN
  (select userid, count(*) as numberofClassfields
   from your_table
   group by userid) c
  on dc.userid=c.userid
ORDER BY dc.numberofDeletedClassfields desc
```

**EDIT2:** Anyway, if you are looking for the maximum number of deleted Classfields, then you can use this:

```
select max(numberofDeletedClassfields)
from (
  select count(*) as numberofDeletedClassfields
  from your_table
  where classStatus = 6
  group by userid) s
```

Comment: Your sql is great :-) But a little overkill.

Comment: @norman I posted an alternative, that uses joins. If you have a lot of users that don't have any deleted classfield, it should be faster! Of course my solution is useful if you have to count both the total number of rows, and the total number of deleted rows, otherwise it could be much more simpler

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) as numberofClassifieds, userid from testtops
where classStatus=6
group by userid
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT userid, COUNT(*) NumberOfClassified
FROM tableName WHERE classStatus = 6 
GROUP BY  userID 
ORDER BY NumberOfClassified DESC limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try query given below

```
SELECT `userid` , count(*) AS numberofClassifieds   FROM `testtops` where  `classStatus` = 6 group by `userid`  order by numberofClassifieds DESC
```

thanks